# How can I launch a new terminal to track my shell script triggered from Django?

Tags: python, django, linux, bash

I'm working on a `Django 2.0.2` project built in `Python 3.6.3`, which requires forking off a shell script as a background child process.

This is how I'm currently triggering it:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(./master.sh)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't echo to the same terminal as the Django server like other processes on the site.

The pipeline outputs to a `log.txt` file after completing, but as some jobs will take hours to complete, I'd like to have a way to follow the job as it happens by spawning a new terminal.

I have tried using `gnome-terminal` commands, but so far I've had no successful readout.

Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Comment: You can try [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), but maybe looking into Celery and making something more robust and flexible would be a better long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly solution is to use something like tmux. It allows you to create a terminal in the background and attach to it later if you wish.

```
tmux new -s hello -d "for((ii=0;ii<100;ii++)); do echo \$ii; sleep 1; done"
```

(use your command in the quotes, instead of for ... done)

This will create a terminal (named hello) in the background to which one can attach using command

```
tmux a -t hello
```

Detach using ctrl-b d